# Can't make Navigation Bar horizontal HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigationbar

```
float: left;
```

and

```
display: inline;
```

are both failing to work.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this navigation bar horizontal?

```css
.navbar li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand">Simmo Simpson</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: try `li.navbar {` in stead of `.navbar li {`

Comment: I don't know it this was intentional but I've added Pixel units to your styles. I've also added the Bootstrap CDN and a snippet.

Comment: Thanks Alex! When I run your code in stackoverflow it does what I want but when I run it in my text editor it remains vertical. I have the CDN in my <head>. Still can't work out my problem. Anyone got any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're doing things the right way, but your code sample misses some tags :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand">Simmo Simpson</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="navbar-link" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-link" class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-link" class="active"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-link" class="active"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <style>
    .navbar li {
        margin: 5;
        padding: 0;
        width: 80;
        float: left;
    }
    </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

will do the trick. You have to say to the browser, what it have to do with those lines : use Html `<html>` and apply that style using `<style>` . If your style directives have to be more important, I think that it could be a better way to create a second file that will contains all your css and to link it with your html document.

EDIT :

The css rule : `.navbar li` will find the navbar class and find all its li childs, so you can remove ids on each li and replace them by a class name

I hope it may help

Comment: Thanks for your reply  @Tony  sorry if my original post wasn't clear. I already have my CSS in another file and am linking it using <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">   Just in case, I tried using <style> tags in the HTML but it's still not working... any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the main.css is not found by your browser : where is it located ? In your comment, it have to be in the same location as your index.html . In the other hand, did you try to copy all the code sample that I provided in my post ? what happens using this one ?

Comment: Solved the problem and posted below.  I needed to use `#navbar` not `.navbar li`, because it was an ID element and not a class element.

Comment: OMG I did see that you're using multiple id with the same value. An id have to appear only once per page. You have to use class if you wanna use it ( i edited my post )

Answer (score 0):

put your css inside style tags or an external css file and include it in the header section of your html

```
  <style>
ul li{ display: inline;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try the following code snippet, it might help you**

```css
.navbar li {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type : none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Simmo Simpson</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">About</a>                 </li>
            <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>              </li>
            <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">Contact</a>              </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks @sumit chauhan   I tried adding using float: left;  and  list-style-type : none; together but it's still not giving me the horizontal layout

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed

> .navbar li {

to

> li.navbar {

```css
li.navbar {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand">Simmo Simpson</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Changing .navbar li  to li.navbar isn't working for me. Are both of these syntaxes acceptable? Is one preferred? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

The

```
 <li id="navbar" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

elements need the corresponding CSS to be

```
#navbar
```

and NOT

```
.navbar li
```

.navbar li should be used in the CSS for the html **class** attribute class="navbar li" whereas #navbar should be used the **ID** attribute

When I changed that, the CSS styling was applied to the html with the corresponding id attribute.